# Laravel 5 Invalid Custom Request - do not redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom `Request` Class on Laravel 5 which handles form inputs (POST). the thing is, I want to use the same request class for a GET method but instead of redirecting the user back to the original request URL (which causes an infinite) loop I want to throw an exception (if the request is not valid), how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom `Request` class, you can override the failedValidation method that is defined in the `FormRequest` class.

I.e. place this method in your `Request` class:

```
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator) {
    throw new \Exception('Error processing request');
}
```

Overriding the response() method can also be used to return a preferred response, personally I have used this to return the errors in JSON form, all that was required to do this was to return a JsonResponse with the errors and response code:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this in your request method:

```
if (Request::isMethod('get'))
{
    //Here you can add your custom exception.
}
```

You can see the documentation for more info about this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#other-request-information

Comment: Yeah but thats in the request itself, the problem is that my request does not passes the validation (rules method) hence it fails and I don't even get to the controller, it just throws me back to the previous URL which is still invalid and then creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @Broshi I need to see some code. I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: This is the request code: http://pastebin.com/dLKXSa6u and this is my `api` controller which handles `GET` requests: http://pastebin.com/8ctJkszi as you can see the controller asks for my `custom request` the thing is that it does not pass and redirecting back to the original URL which is invalid hence the infinite loop...